# kimurai gem - works on development, not in production - Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: url)

Tags: web-scraping, kimurai

The code works fine on my local computer (development), but in production, when I try to run de scrape method it raise an error: Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: url). Is there any special configuration for KimuraiGem for production? Using rbenv Ruby -v 3.0.1 Rails -v 6.1.4.1 Unicorn and nginx

FATAL -- milenios_spider: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"milenios_spider", :status=>:failed, :error=>"#<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keyword: url)>", :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2021-10-31 23:14:29.30478516 +0000, :stop_time=>2021-10-31 23:14:33.352345259 +0000, :running_time=>"4s", :visits=>{:requests=>1, :responses=>1}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}

In my controller:

```
  def scrape
      url = "https://www..some page...com"
      response = MileniosSpider.process(url)
      if response[:status] == :completed && response[:error].nil?
        flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully scraped url"
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = response[:error]
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"
  end
```

Model:

```
  class MileniosSpider < Kimurai::Base
    @name = 'milenios_spider'
    @engine = :mechanize
    @config = {
      restart_if: { memory_limit: 350_000 },
      before_request: { delay: 1..2 }
    }

    def self.process(url)
      @start_urls = [url]
      self.crawl!
    end

   
    def parse(response, url:, data: {}) 
       .........some code .....
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of ruby are you using in development? I don't think Kimurai supports Ruby 3.x yet, which is what you are using in production. You can downgrade the project's Ruby version or try to run Kimurai with a different version of Ruby via the command line.

**https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework/issues/58**

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(response, data = {})
    .........some code .....
end
```

Parse method accepts 2 parameters only